# Confused by git filter-branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I need to analyse what exactly happened to a some files in a given directory during the whole history and using things like `git log the_directory` is not good enough. So I though I'd create a branch containing only relevant files.

I wrote a perl script `remove-all-but-stuff` and verified it works correctly. Initially, I thought that simply removing the files would do, but then I fixed it to use

```
system qw(git rm -r --ignore-unmatch --quiet), @files
```

where `@files` contains the unwanted directories and files *as they are found in the working tree - may this be a problem?*

I created a new branch and filtered it via

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter remove-all-but-stuff my-branch
```

and at the end the files are gone, but this happens in the very last commit. The history contains changes to files which shouldn't exist.

I'm using git version 2.3.5. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

---

Now I even added some paths to `@files` without looking at if there exist. Something has changed (Ref 'refs/heads/my-branch' was rewritten), but unwanted files (even below the added paths) are still in the history.

Comment: I'm just leaving this here : git gui blame somefile.txt provide a GUI presenting the file and the origin of all the modification. you can navigate the history of the file by clicking on the hash of the commit related to each line. This is the best way (imo) to look at the history of a file in depth.

Comment: @FélixCantournet My problem is a bunch of files and many changes in them (and only two renames). Specifying them on the command line is a big pain because of files with blanks in names and similar crimes. What I've got after the filtering is much much better.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather stupid, but it was an error on my side.<sup>1</sup> I overlooked a (well hidden) error message. The problem was

```
error: the following files have changes staged in the index:
```

(hidden at the end of a line and followed by maybe hundreds of files). I guess, I forgot the `-f` modifier (also also forgot to bail out on error).

Actually, it looks like there's no reason to use `git rm` instead of `/bin/rm` together with `--tree-filter`.

---

<sup>1 I considered removing my question, however, it may save someone quite some time.</sup>